# adding user in java CRUD web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, crud

This is my first CRUD Web application based on Java. I am using Eclipse, Tomcat EE server, and MySQL database. The application contains basically a list of users with first name, last name, date of birth, phone number, email, address.
At this point I want to make possible adding a new user to the list of users, still cannot figure out where the problem is, and why I cannot make it work. 
Here is part of the code referring to the problem.

This is the servlet:
 `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String page = "";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equals("addUser")) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            user.setPhoneNumber(request.getParameter("phoneNumber"));
            user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            String month = request.getParameter("month");
            String day = request.getParameter("day");
            String year = request.getParameter("year");
            user.setDob(UserController.parseDate(month, day, year));
            boolean addUs = dbUtil.addUser(user);
            if (addUs) {
                page = "/UsersList.jsp";
            } else {
                page = "/AddUser.jsp";
            }
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        doGet(request, response);
    }`

And here is the DAO Implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean addUser(User user) {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, phoneNumber, email)"
                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
        stmt.setString(2, user.getLastName());
        stmt.setDate(3, (Date) user.getDob());
        stmt.setString(4, user.getPhoneNumber());
        stmt.setString(5, user.getEmail());
        stmt.executeQuery();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println("Error with connection.");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am ready to share any additional information if necessary.

Comment: Could you share the error message?

Comment: There is not error message. As you can see, the method addUser(User user), that actually adds the user to the list in the database returns boolean type result. So I always receive result - false, and the servlet sends me back to the same page - AddUser.jsp.

Comment: As you can see, the method `addUser(User)` returns _false_ only if it catches an exception. You always receive _false_ means that there's always something wrong in this method. Try to modify the `System.err.println("Error with connection.");` to `System.err.println(sqle);` to print the real exception trace please.